# Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS remove the slashes in the url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect the users of my website from HTTP to HTTPS.

Redirecting the base url `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.exmaple.com` work fine, but `http://www.example.com/data` is redirected to `https//www.example.comdata` without the `/`  between `.com` and `data`.

My  full actual .htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also have another rule in my virtualhost configuration:

```
 Redirect / https://www.example.com
```

Comment: It is not apparent from that code, why this should go wrong. `%{REQUEST_URI}` is supposed to contain the full path component of the requested URL, including the leading slash. And testing your code with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be also confirms, that this should work. Is this _all_ your .htaccess contains? Try and put the flags `[R=302, L]` at the end of the rule, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: This my  full .htaccess updated.  any  idea .?

Comment: You are missing the `[L,R=301]` behind the actual HTTPS rewrite rule there (only the one commented out a bit further up contains it), so that the process will continue evaluating the following rules.

Comment: Please check   https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=bed2bdcf-8046-44be-88d0-e1a3e37b2091       this  example  still doesnt work   http://osradar.com/ads.txt

Answer (score 2):

> I have also another rule in virtualhost
>
> ```
> Redirect / https://www.example.com
> ```

You are missing a trailing slash on the target URL in the `Redirect` directive. So, it will end up redirecting `/foo` to `https://www.example.comfoo`. The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching; everything *after* the match is appended to the end of the target URL. This rule - in the VirtualHost - takes priority over the mod_rewrite directive in `.htaccess`.

This should read:

```
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
```

If you notice in the network traffic, it is also prefixing the `www` subdomain - which is also not present in the mod_rewrite directive.

If you have this `Redirect` in the `<VirtualHost>` container for port 80 (providing it covers both www and non-www requests) then you don't need the corresponding mod_rewrite directive in `.htaccess` to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: i want to thank you.  adding  /  on the  virtualhost redirect  option has   solved  my issue.  problem solved

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer on the left below the voting arrows (to help other users and remove the question from the unanswered question queue). You can also upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)